# Meaning of 向き合う姿勢が出来

Tags: meaning

> **向き合う姿勢が出来つつある。**

I couldn't find any references to help me understand the meaning of this sentence.

**向き合う**: 1. to be opposite; to face each other​, 2. to confront (an issue); to face.

**姿勢**: 1. posture; pose; position; stance; carriage (of the body)​, 2. attitude; approach; stance.

**出来**: 1. workmanship; craftsmanship; execution; finish, 2. grades; results; score; record​, 3. quality (e.g. of a crop)​, 4. dealings; transactions.

Does it mean: "I'm taking a stance to confront/face it (problem/issue)"?

Thank you for your kind guidance.

Comment: Hello, just one remark if this can help: 出来つつある can be replaced by 出来ている（できている）.

Comment: @Gumamori But it changes the meaning. [How close are なりつつある and なっている?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3717/5010)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that actually! Thanks @naruto ! Should I erase my message to avoid any misguidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 向き合う: 1. to be opposite; to face each other​, 2. to confront (an issue); to face.

Probably meaning 2 here.

> 姿勢: 1. posture; pose; position; stance; carriage (of the body)​, 2. attitude; approach; stance.

Again probably meaning 2 here.

> 出来: 1. workmanship; craftsmanship; execution; finish, 2. grades; results; score; record​, 3. quality (e.g. of a crop)​, 4. dealings; transactions.

No, [つつ ending](https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MDJ%A4%C4%A4%C4%A4%A2%A4%EB) plus できる.

> Does it mean: "I'm taking a stance to confront/face it (problem/issue)"?

Yes, that is the gist of it, but the できつつ part implies that they are making gradual improvements, so it's more like "I am becoming more and more able to face the problem" etc. 姿勢 when used as meaning 2 above (but not for meaning 1, body posture) is quite a vague catch-all word in Japanese so sometimes you can throw it away when translating.