# How to wear clothes?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

There are several Japanese verbs for 'to wear', depending on the kind of clothes. What if one wears several? What is 'wear' if 'I wear a shirt, pants, glasses and a hat'? Does one of かぶる, 着る, 履く and かける trump the others? or is the choice based on a specific item (probably the last one) in the list?

Comment: You can use 身につける.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4968/9831