# ている/ていた時 understanding

Tags: grammar, translation, nuances, tense

I understand how 時 works with plain present/plain past (e.g. 食べる/食べた時) but I'm a little unsure of ている/ていた時.

Also what's the difference between these two sentences:

> 私がお風呂に入っ**ている時**電話が鳴った。
>
> 私がお風呂に入っ**ていた時**電話が鳴った。

In a textbook apparently they both translate as "When I was taking a bath, the telephone rang."
But I don't understand why.

If someone could please explain this for me I'd really appreciate it! (I hope it's not too broad a question.)

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21422/9749

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is the kind of thing I need right now! :D