# た or ていた? Is "turned right" a state or an action?

Tags: grammar, て-form, tense, conditionals

In this link, [Past Unreal Conditional](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25179/past-unreal-conditional/25186#comment62906_25186), user l'électeur has given an answer pointing to the tense issues in the original sentence given in the question, stating that ていた needs to be used instead of た:

> あのとき右に曲がれば、どうなっただろう。
>
> If I had turned right back then, I wonder what would have happened.

l'électeur has given the following corrected sentences:

> 「あのとき右に**曲がっていたのなら（ば）**、どう**なっていた**（の）だろう(or のであろう)。」
>
> or
>
> 「あのとき右に**曲がっていれば**(or **いたら**)、どう**なっていた**（の）だろう(or のであろう)。」

However, I would like to know **why exactly ていた and not just た must be used for both 曲がる and なる**. I am aware that ていた expresses a state while た focuses on the action, but I simply cannot comprehend why one would choose to focus on "the state of turning right" rather than regretting his decision of not "taking the action of turning right".

I have done some research on these tenses myself, and one source I have found is the following question, which I have derived the "state" vs "action" idea from:

[What is the difference between using ている、ていた、た in relative clauses?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21422/what-is-the-difference-between-using-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F-%E3%81%9F-in-relative-clauses)

Comment: I never meant to imply that 「曲がっていた」 meant "was turning".  I meant to say that it meant "had turned".   That is how the pluperfect is formed in Japanese and, incidentally, that is how the past progressive is also formed.  It is a  grammar point that seems to really confuse the learner.  From the context, though, you will always know which tense we meant to use.

Comment: @l'électeur Ah, my apologies, I wasn't trying to misquote you, if I did. Anyways, I think I see it now. Will attempt to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a shot at answering this, after l'électeur helped me straighten out some things:

> あのとき右に**曲がれば**、どう**なった**だろう。

would probably be fitting for "If I **turned** right back then, I wonder **what events would have taken place**." This sentence seems to emphasise the action of turning, and the process of resulting actions taking place.

> あのとき右に**曲がっていた**のなら（ば）、どう**なっていた**（の）だろう。

would probably be fitting for "If I **had turned** right back then, I wonder **what would have happened**." This sentence seems to emphasise the state of "had turned", and the state of affairs that would have resulted.

Comment: "If I had turned right back then" and "Had I turned right back then" sound the same to me. I think the difference is between "If I turned right back then" (first sentence), and "If I **had** turned right back then" (second sentence).  In English I would argue that the first sentence is just as ropey as it is in Japanese.

Comment: @user3856370 I see, good point - will modify. Thanks!