# Difference between 溺れた人, 溺れている人 and 溺れる人

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, aspect

> そのとき海岸の近くでは、州の職員などがドローンを使って**溺れた**人を助ける練習をしていました。
>   At that time, near the coast, some people were practicing rescuing people who **have drowned** using a drone.
>   男の子たちが**溺れた**ことを知った人たちは、ドローンを沖に飛ばしました。
>   The people who new the boys **had drowned** flew the drone to the open sea.
>   ドローンは、**溺れた**人を助ける道具を男の子たちのすぐ近くに落としました。
>   The drone dropped a device to rescue the people who **had drowned** right next to them.

I don't understand why 溺れた is used in these sentences, rather than 溺れている, or even 溺れる. It seems to me that at the time of rescue the people are either drowning now or will drown rather than having already drowned.

I'm not sure if I'm having a problem with this specific verb or if it indicates a bigger hole in my understanding of aspect in relative clauses. I tried reading [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11975/what-are-the-general-principles-of-using-verbs-to-modify-nouns-e-g-%E7%84%A6%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88-%E7%84%A6%E3%81%92%E3%81%9F), [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21422/what-is-the-difference-between-using-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F-%E3%81%9F-in-relative-clauses) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/%E5%A4%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E7%8C%AB-vs-%E5%A4%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E7%8C%AB/3364#3364.) but I have to admit to being completely mystified.

Comment: 英語の「drown」は「溺れ死ぬ、溺死する/させる」だけど日本語の「溺れる」は死ぬところまで含まないんですよね・・・ English "drown" means "おぼれ死ぬ、溺死する/させる" while Japanese "溺れる" means "(be) nearly drown(ed)", "is drowning"

Comment: Right.Though  **溺れた** has a bit of nuance those who drowned are almost, 70% lol near about to die. haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion is due to your translation of 溺れる to mean drown (to death). This is a better translation:

> 溺れる　　水中に落ちこんで死にそうになる。Fall into water and potentially die.

The only definite thing that we can ascertain from the use of 溺れる is that they were submerged. In this case, in water.

> 溺れた人 Person who WAS under the surface (was drowning).
>
> 溺れている人 Person who IS under the surface (is drowning).

Comment: That's another way to say it. 意味は全く変わらないと思いますが。

Comment: risk one's life, risk death... おんなぢでしょー　＾＾ 両方の言い方があるねー　なんかニュアンス違うの？

Comment: Evel Knievel risked his life every time he made a jump. Evel Knievel risked death each time he made a jump. ふむふむ…特にニュアンスという違いはないとおもうよー。

Comment: @iser27280, Chocolate: 英語は詳しくないのですが、death と lifeとは全く逆の言葉ですので論理的に同じということはないはずです。lifeは「（命などを）危うくする、かける」、deathは「危険を冒す‌​」のように、別の意味があるのではないでし‌​ょうか。「溺れる」ときは自殺でないのなら‌​、一般に自分の命が危険に晒されるでしょう‌​。英語-英語辞典で用法を調べますとlif‌​eが来る場合とdeath等のマイナス要因‌​とが来る場合とでは同じriskでも違う状‌​況のように思います。しかし、質問者の「溺‌​れる」と違う議論になりますのでコメントは‌​これ以上なしということでお願いします。

Comment: @mackygoo, Chocolate: For sake of clarity (and to avoid confusion) I have amended my answer. 勘違いされる可能性をなくするため、もう少し明確な応答に改善しました。

Comment: fall into water and risk death 水に落ちて死の危険を冒す、fall into water and risk one's life 水に落ちて命を危険にさらす、。。。今回の回答で前者がだめで後者でなくてはおかしい、とわざわざ訂正を求めるほどの理由は見つかりませんけどね…。risk death って言い方を単に知らなかっただけじゃないのかしらと思ってしまうですけどｗ　これ以上コメントなしでお願いとか自分の言いたいことだけ言ってこっちは反論すんなってことねｗいつものｗｗ

Comment: @mackygoo Unless I misunderstand, I don't think "risk one's life" is appropriate here. This phrase suggest that the act is intentional. e.g. "He ignored the warning signs and risked his life by swimming anyway".

Comment: @user3856370   I concur. I was conflating 'be at risk of losing one's life' with actively 'risking one's life', then I walked myself into a fallacy-hole by reactively defending my  dumb position.

Comment: @user27280, Chocolate, user3856370「溺れる」の 英訳として 「"to fall into water and risk one's life"ではないでしょうか。」としましたが、間違って解釈したと判断しましたので、先に出したコメントを削除します。