# How do you describe or specify a person with verbs? (convert verbs to adjectives)

Tags: verbs, adjectives

How do you describe or specify a specific target person by their current verb in action?
Or perhaps more simply, how do you use a verb as an adjective?

Here are some examples:

- The **man wearing** a hat is handsome. *(alt. The **hat-wearing man** is handsome.)*
- Is the **person singing** your friend? *(alt. Is the **singing-person** your friend?)*
- The **child screaming** is holding candy. *(alt. The **screaming-child** is holding candy.)*

If I was to guess the grammar, perhaps:

1. 帽子【ぼうし】をかぶる男【おとこ】の人【ひと】はかっこいい。
2. 歌う【うたう】人は友達【ともだち】ですか？
3. 叫ぶ【さけぶ】子供【こども】はキャンディを持って【もって】いる。

or do I use the present continuous:

1. 帽子をかぶっている男の人はかっこいい。
2. 歌っている人は友達ですか？
3. 叫んでいる子供はキャンディを持っている。

Comment: To add to your confusion you'd rather say 帽子をかぶった男.

Comment: Confusion has certainly been added  Are you saying that to use past tense is more correct? Or another option?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74598/11104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. 帽子【ぼうし】をかぶる男【おとこ】の人【ひと】はかっこいい<s>だ</s>。
> 2. 歌う【うたう】人は友達【ともだち】ですか？
> 3. 叫ぶ【さけぶ】子供【こども】はキャンディを持って【もって】いる。

These are not very natural. 「Plain form verb + 人」 can mean "someone who will / is going to do~~", so these examples may sound like "The man who will wear a hat..." "Is the person who will sing..." "The child who will scream..." 帽子をかぶる男の人 could also mean "A man who usually/often wears a hat."

And かっこいい**だ** is incorrect. You don't attach a copula だ to an i-adjective.

> 1. 帽子をかぶっ**ている**男の人はかっこいい<s>だ</s>。
> 2. 歌っ**ている**人は友達ですか？
> 3. 叫ん**でいる**子供はキャンディを持っている。

These sentences are fine. They mean "The man who is wearing a hat..." "Is the person who is singing..." "The child who is screaming..."

---

As a side note, #1 can be rephrased as 帽子をかぶっ**た**男の人は...
歌っ**た**人 and 叫ん**だ**子供 would mean "the person who **sang**" and "the child who **screamed**", respectively. 歌っ**ていた**人 and 叫ん**でいた**子供 would mean "the person who **was singing**" and "the child who **was screaming**".
To say "The man who **wore/was wearing** a hat...", you'd say 帽子をかぶっ**ていた**男の人.

For more on 「かぶっ**ている**人」「かぶっ**た**人」, 「持っ**ている**人」「持っ**た**人」, 「着**ている**人」「着**た**人」 etc., please refer to there threads:

- [Use of かける (N5 question)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29671/9831)
- ["太ってる猫" vs "太った猫"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3361/9831)
- [Why does 音を表したことば use the past tense?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43864/9831)

Comment: Thank you! I have since edited (removed) the だ from the original question to avoid distraction from the grammar focus of my question.

Comment: I just want to add a note of gratitude to your side-note about using past-tense verbs… the links we're very helpful, particularly the "太ってる猫" vs "太った猫" link, which explained the usage very well.

Answer (score 0):

帽子をかぶる男の人はかっこいいだ means “The man who wears a hat is handsome.” You could be referring to someone who is or is not present; it’s more ambiguous. On the other hand, 帽子をかぶっている男の人はかっこいいだ means “The man who is wearing a hat is handsome,” which better implies that the subject in question is present.

Comment: I don't think it's advisable to leave the ungrammatical だ in the sentences without any correction to it.

Comment: Thank you! I have since edited (removed) the だ from the original question to avoid distraction from the grammar focus of my question.