why is 離れた used when describing distance from a place
When I read this sentence I don't understand why the writer uses 離れた instead of 離れる. To me 離れた has the nuance of the past but the writer is refering to the store that is existing now in the writer point of time.
Aは今日も遠く離れた店に出かけるんだろうか。

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11975/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3361/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29671/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43864/9831 -- Compare 焦げたトースト・焦げているトースト、太った猫・太っている猫、眼鏡をかけた人・眼鏡をかけている人、離れた店・離れている店

離れる is a verb, and 離れた is a modification for 店.
"I wonder that A is again off to a far store today?"
