# Explanation for 変わった and 似た as adjectivals

Tags: grammar, tense, relative-clauses

I often see the two verbs 変わる and 似る used in their た-form when modifying nouns and I'm not really sure exactly how to make sense of them.

変わる: e.g. as in 「変わった人」. Here I'm wondering why it's not just always「変わっている」 instead. I'm truly no expert, but I would have read 変わった人 as "a person who changed" rather than "a person who is different".

似た: e.g. as in 「似た者同士」. Like with 変わった, I would again have expected 似ている here.

Does this have something to do with the difference between static and punctual verbs?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Related: [What are the general principles of using verbs to modify nouns (e.g. 焦げるトースト/焦げたトースト)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11975/5010) / [“太ってる猫” vs “太った猫”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3361/5010)