# Referring to groups of people

Tags: grammar

If I was to refer to people who like fish, I'd say something like 「魚が好きな人」, but if I was to refer to people who do something, how would I go about saying that? Would the format be similar, or would it be completely different. I know in Japanese, to like is treated as an adjective, where as, someone doing something would be a verb, so if I was to refer to people who wear pants, would I say it as something like this 「ズボンを履いている人」? I'm not sure if I'd use the TE form of the verb, or if I'd have to use a different form, nor am I sure if I need to use いる or ある. I went with いる, as I'm referring to a live, animate person, but I'm not even sure if I'm even remotely close to saying it properly. Is there some other particle I'd need to use, or a different sentence structure? Or would referring to a group of people based on something they do, such as people who wear something, people who exercise, or certain actions be unnatural in Japanese?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11975/what-are-the-general-principles-of-using-verbs-to-modify-nouns-e-g-%e7%84%a6%e3%81%92%e3%82%8b%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88-%e7%84%a6%e3%81%92%e3%81%9f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the general principles of using verbs to modify nouns (e.g. 焦げるトースト/焦げたトースト)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11975/what-are-the-general-principles-of-using-verbs-to-modify-nouns-e-g-%e7%84%a6%e3%81%92%e3%82%8b%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88-%e7%84%a6%e3%81%92%e3%81%9f)