# ています form or past tense?

Tags: grammar

I recently came across a sentence that said 「友達はよく、寝たふりをしています」which translates to "My friend often acts like he’s sleeping." My question is, why was past tense of 寝る used here? Shouldn’t it be 「友達はよく寝ているふりをしています」

Comment: ふり is a noun and this is related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3361/43676

Comment: I guess both work mostly because, as a state, 寝た and 寝ている are the same - you lie with your eyes closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question: ["太ってる猫" vs "太った猫"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3361/9831)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["太ってる猫" vs "太った猫"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/%e5%a4%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b%e7%8c%ab-vs-%e5%a4%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e7%8c%ab)

Answer (score 1):

Here the friend acting like he has slept. In English sentence, "slept" is used. The act of sleeping is already in the past. I can write an English translation:

> My friend often pretends as if he has slept.

That's why 寝たふり

Answer (score -1):

- 「寝たふり」：Pretending as if he "fell asleep."
- 「寝ているふり」：Pritending as if he "is asleep."